# missing turnover

Tags: wallet, receiving

I read what you wrote about missing turnover. I also got told this. They told me I just have to put a certain amount of BTC to my wallet because of the circulation. When I have this amount in my wallet, the hash could be completed and I could receive the money. Did anyone do this before? If I put BTC in my wallet, no one could take it out, so is this a try of scamming or not? Does anyone know about rules and regulation?

Comment: It's a scam,  100% certainly. They have access to the wallet that you don't know about. There's no need to keep posting the same question here. You are being tricked and should stop communicating with those people and discard that wallet.

Comment: Let me rephrase that… Someone is asking you to deposit money into a wallet which you didn't create under the dubious ruse of wanting to gift you money you didn't expect. Raises a few alarm bells, but that's just me.

Comment: Please read the answer on the linked question.